# Minimize application during active ProgressDialog

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

Is there a way to give the user the option to minimize the application while showing the [ProgressDialog](https://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html)?

```
controller = await dialogCoordinator.ShowProgressAsync(this, "Header", "Message, please wait...");
```

It currently remains opened and user is unable to minimize or move the window.

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the window before calling this ProgressDialog? I'm wondering if this call is un-minimizing the window.

Comment: @sean would like the option to minimize everything after the dialog appears

Comment: Have you tried calling the progress bar without the `await`? unless you need that to hold your main thread?

Answer (score 1):

We've had the same requirement on our Application which lead us to develop our own ProgressBar control and place it on a layer on top of the Application, in the MainView which left the top bar including the minimize and maximize buttons - working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing is general and has nothing to do with the dialog you are displaying. If mahapps.metro is really just a toolkit, standard solutions should work

```
Appplication.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized
```

If this still doesn't work for you, it means that you are in the "framework in the framework" situation and have to get out of the box using some win32 interop like ShowWindow(...)

Comment: to clarify I want to give user the option, for example through a button click on the dlialog.   If I did that, I would just set the WindowState to Minimized when user clicks the button?

Answer (score 0):

Hi we also faced this issue, after lots of months of searching in google and gitter ,
I found that there is a property in the metroWindow class (which is this,in the author example)

> metroWindow.ShowDialogsOverTitleBar

once I set it to false , I was able to minimize my application via the title bar ,
hopes it helps anyone.